# I can't find the text in a pop-up Window using Robotium

Tags: android, automation, functional-testing, robotium

I have been using Robotium for the last couple weeks writing test cases for an app. It's a great tool but there is one thing that I cannot seem to get working. The app I'm using creates a pop-up window regardless if you are in the app or not to notify the user and when looking at the UI Automator Viewer is is still tied to the same package that I am testing.

The issue is that I cannot read any text or click on anything in the window through Robotium. I created a test to see if Robotium can even see it going through all of the views in debug mode by hand but it seems to be transparent to it. Does anyone know a way around this or another program that would be ideal for this?

Comment: did you got to the solution for this?